# In JavaScript, how do I write a function that receives a named element to conditionally push into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

New to JavaScript and coding, and working on a Parking Garage program that parks cars and checks which cars are parked.

I am starting with a function parkCar () that receives a car name and pushes it into an array, on the condition that there is enough room, setting a max of 7 on parked cars. I am getting stuck on how to code the function so that I can specify the names of the cars I am parking in the garage.

Right now, the program is successfully adding carName to parkedCars up to the max string length of the array, but when I use the console to check the items in the array I get ["carName," "carName"] etc. rather than ["volvo," "prius"] etc. How can I create a variable that allows for unique input of car names into the array?

Code pasted below:

```
console.log('Enter CarName to park in Anne Lot');
var carName;
const maxCars=7
var parkedCars=[];
var carName

parkCar=function (){
  if(parkedCars.length<=maxCars){
    parkedCars.push('');
    console.log(parkedCars);
    console.log("Welcome to Anne's Lot.");
    }

  else {
    console.log("Sorry, Anne's Lot is at max capacity.");
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you actually defining the `carName`? Because right now you're just defining `var carName` twice and `.push`ing an empty string. Also on a technicality note, if you're looking for unique you should add an object to the array, since "prius" and "volvo" are not unique to cars. something like `parkedCars.push({ make: "Toyota", "model": "Prius", licensePlate: "1234567" });`

Answer (score 1):

```
parkCar=function (cName){ // accept car name value
  if(parkedCars.length<=maxCars){
    parkedCars.push(cName); // push name of car here.
    console.log(parkedCars);
    console.log("Welcome to Anne's Lot.");
    }

  else {
    console.log("Sorry, Anne's Lot is at max capacity.");
  }
}
```

Comment: parkCar("volvo");

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log('Enter CarName to park in Anne Lot');
var carName;
const maxCars=7;
var parkedCars=[];

parkCar=function (carName){
  if(parkedCars.length<=maxCars){
    parkedCars.push(carName);
    console.log(parkedCars);
    console.log("Welcome to Anne's Lot.");
    }

  else {
    console.log("Sorry, Anne's Lot is at max capacity.");
  }
}
```

Then in your console type

```
parkCar('Car1');
```

and so on, up to 7 cars.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how do get enter a named element, it's pretty standard to use `prompt(message)` in a development environment. Other considerations:

It's generally a good idea to avoid `var` where possible so you don't run into unexpected behavior. `let` works fine here.

Change `if(parkedCars.length <= maxCars)` to `if(parkedCars.length < maxCars)`, so the function won't allow the user to push a final, 8th car if the `parkingCars` has 7 entries. If this was intended and you wanted the user to be able to store 8 cars in the lot, change `maxCars` to 8 as this is more intuitive.

Define the car name as an argument to your function. Here I renamed it to `parkingCar` so there's no confusion between the argument and the outer `carName` variable. I also added `if(parkingCar)` to handle the scenario where the user doesn't enter anything.

This is more stylistic but it's a good idea to put space around operators and operands to make your code more readable.

If you're creating a function as a Named Function Expression, it's best practice to follow the final curly brace with a semicolon to avoid unintended behavior.

All that considered, here is how I'd implement the function:

```
let carName = prompt('Enter CarName to park in Anne Lot');
const maxCars = 7
let parkedCars = [];

let parkCar = function(parkingCar) {
  if(parkingCar && parkedCars.length < maxCars){
    parkedCars.push(parkingCar);
    console.log(parkedCars);
    console.log("Welcome to Anne's Lot.");
  }
  else if(parkingCar) {
    console.log("Sorry, Anne's Lot is at max capacity.");
  } else {
    console.log("Sorry, nothing to park");
  }
};

parkCar(carName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want your `parkCar` function to accept an *argument*. This should be the car that you want to park. The placeholder for an argument is called a *parameter*. The name of the parameter can be anything, but it helps a lot to give it a name that instantly makes it clear what the function does and what values it accepts. In the example below I've called the parameter `car`.

The argument is the value that you pass into a function in the spot of the parameter. Give the `parkCar` function an argument and add the car that you want to your array.

```
var parkCar = function(car) {
  if (parkedCars.length < maxCars) {
    parkedCars.push(car);
  }
}
```

Add the cars like this.

```
parkCar('audi');
parkCar('volvo');
parkCar('mercedes');
```